# Assets field inside grid inside fluid

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, grid, ee4, fluid-field

I’m having an issue where I'm using Assets (EEharbor) inside a EE Grid, inside an EE Fluid field. I think I have the tags correctly set up, it’s outputting the correct number of results (files) from the assets field, but all the rendered tags have the same content.

Has anyone encountered this before? This is my mark up.

```
{cf_fluid}     
    {cf_fluid:cf_fluid_downloads}
         {content}
            {content:download_title}<br>
            {content:file_downloads}
                {content:file_downloads:filename}
                {content:file_downloads:title}<br>
            {/content:file_downloads}
        {/content}
   {/cf_fluid:cf_fluid_downloads}
{/cf_fluid}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing exact same issue. How dit you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

I think Assets is not supported within Fluid field natively.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs...

> For now, you can add an Assets field to a Fluid field by putting it
>   inside a Grid field.